# Attach media to multiple posts

Tags: theme-development, attachments, media, media-library

I have a simple code where I am attaching existing in the library image to a post:

```
function attachToPost($attachmentId, $postId){
    return wp_update_post(array(
        'ID' => (int)$attachmentId,
        'post_parent' => (int)$postId
    ));
}
```

The problem is that I can't attach it to a second post.
I read in the internet that this is the way that WordPress works, but is there some kind of solution ?

I don't prefer plugins.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to assign multiple parents to the attachment. However, there is an alternative solution. You can use     `update_post_meta`.   to store the attachment id to the post and similarly, you can use function `get_post_meta`.   for getting the attachment id.

Comment: Can you provide an example on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to use `set_post_thumbnail( $postId, $attachmentId );`. With it, I can have one image attached to many posts.

Comment: `set_post_thumbnail()` is clearly for _Sets the post thumbnail (featured image) for the given post._

Comment: Yes, but in my case it doesn't matter, I am using the REST API and what and how I set there as a response is what and how the client uses, which is a React app.